# Chrome GET query : net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: google-chrome, networking

i'm starting to get this error message from time to time in my nav. console.

```
.../assets/img/logo.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

What could be possible of it?

Comment: the url is not in correct format, so the browser cant find that image?

Comment: @wijaya it's in its correct format, sometimes it works perfectly sometimes not.

Comment: I am facing a same issue, don't know why but FF/IE have no problem. this happens especially with in png images in random occasion.